# Wikipedia Table Scraper

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I created this small script to strip the data out of tables that have hyperlinks as their `<th />` elements. I was hoping to get input on code clarity and possibly simplification, efficiency is not much of an issue for me as there are not any huge tables on Wikipedia.

```
var arr = $('tbody').children('tr').map(function(idx) {
  return(idx === 0) ?
  {
    rows: $('th', this).map(function(idx) {
      return {
        href: $('a', this).attr('href'),
        title: $('a', this).text()
      }
    }).get()
  } : {
    href: $('th a', this).attr('href'),
    title: $('th a', this).text(),
    rows: $('td', this).map(function(idx) {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get()
  }
}).get();
```

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Mathematical_expressions) is an example of a table that this scraper can be run on.

Comment: Could you show an example table that this can be run on?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Added to question thanks for looking! You can try it out by running it in the developer console in any browser as wikipedia uses JQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks pretty nice, I only have a few nit-picks, really.

What you call "rows" are actually "columns". It's a bit misleading.
The rows are actually the `var arr` that you're making.

The ternary is a bit confusing. 
If clarity is important to you (as you mentioned),
then I think a good old-fashioned if-else would be better.

Lastly, the `idx` function parameters in the inner `map` calls are unused, so you could just as well drop them.

Comment: _The ternary is a bit confusing.._ +1. Especially when it become such enormous one as in the code. BTW: `else` keyword doesn't even needed when we replace the ternary with `if` construct in this case (because of `return` use).